# Pandas - check for string matches in different columns with column values being comma separated

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a df like the following:

```
Col1         Col2

SM_          SM_
SM_          N_
EX_,SM_      EX_,CO_
SL_,N_       PD_,SL_
```

I want to compare both columns, and see if a value in Col1 is present in Col2 or not. Multiple values in both columns are comma separated. So, ideally the result of the row wise comparison shown above should be:

```
True
False
True
True
```

I have the following code right now:

```
finaldf['C'] = finaldf.apply(lambda x: x.Extracted_pillars in x.min_pillar_score, axis=1)
```

This works for single code values, but when each column has multiple values, this does not work properly.

Comment: I removed my answer because it seems that there are more possible cases in your dataframe. You could add more rows to your sample to make it clear what can appear there. We can't predict everything.

Comment: I have added more rows, please help?! thanks

Comment: When I check it with the solution I provided before, I get same results as expected: True, False, True, True. The order of elements in each row doesn't change anything.

Comment: that solution gives FALSE  if Col1==EX_ , MA_  and Col2==EX_

Comment: You mean when there is a space before or after comma?

Comment: youre right, it works, i removed the space

Comment: can you please post the solution, so i can accept it here? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good, but you need to split each string by comma and use `any`.

**EDIT:**

It turns out there are cases when there is a space before or after comma. Then you can use:

```
finaldf['C'] = finaldf.apply(lambda x: any(i in x.Col1.replace(' ', '').split(',')
                                           for i in x.Col2.replace(' ', '').split(',')),
                                           axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
```

Comment: This returns false if Col1==SM_ , N_    and Col2==N_,SM_

Comment: this also returns false if Col1==EX_ , SM_     and  Col2==EX_,MA_

Comment: Please look at the edited answer. It works for cases when there is some extra space.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a function that for each cell constructs a set of the comma-separated values and returns whether the intersection of those sets in a row is not empty:

```py
import pandas as pd

def columns_overlap(row):
    sets = [set(s.split(',')) for s in row]
    intersection = set.intersection(*sets)
    return intersection != set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['SM_', 'SM_', 'EX_,SM_', 'SL_,N_'],
                   'Col2': ['SM_', 'N_', 'EX_,CO_', 'PD_,SL_']})

df['C'] = df.apply(columns_overlap, axis=1)
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
    Col1     Col2     C
0   SM_      SM_      True
1   SM_      N_       False
2   EX_,SM_  EX_,CO_  True
3   SL_,N_   PD_,SL_  True
```

Comment: thanks so much! that's brilliant, I already accepted the other answer before though :)